# c: fscanf trouble including newline character

Tags: c

I'm reading this text from a file:

```
file1: file2,file3,file4
file10: testfile.h
file1: file9
```

and splitting it

```
while(fscanf(fp,"%[^:]: %s",map[i].name, map[i].filesNeeded) == 2)
{
    printf("%s %s",map[i].name, map[i].filesNeeded);
    i++;
}
```

The problem is that the second and third variables are saved with leading newline characters:

```
Details:{name = "\\nfile10", '\\000' <repeats 56 times>, filesNeeded = "testfile.h", '\\000' <repeat
```

How can i save it without the leading newline characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add space for `" %[^:]: %s "`

```
while(fscanf(fp," %[^:]: %s ",map[i].name, map[i].filesNeeded) == 2)
```

the space in the scanf absorbs the space characters, tabulation characters, new line characters